# Slope calculation in R after removing zero or NA values

Tags: r, time-series, regression, linear-regression

I am calculating trend of a time series raster against time data but because of NA and Zero values I am not getting correct results.

In the example below values of a pixel is given. Because of zero values I am getting the value of slope as -23.275 instead of 3.897

```
time Value
1     289
2     289
3     353
4     305
5     0
6     0
7     385
8     0
9     0
10    305
11    0
12    0
13    0
14    0
15    0

correct form should be like this

Time Value
1     289
2     289
3     353
4     305
7     385
10    305
```

My sample code is

```
library(raster)

setwd("F:\\PHD_work\\Paper_work\\EOS\\New folder")
eos = stack(list.files(pattern='*.img'))
time = 1:nlayers(eos)
f_slope=function(x) { if (is.na(x[1])){ NA } else { m = lm(x ~ time); summary(m)$coefficients[2] }}
z = calc(eos, f_slope)
y = writeRaster(z, filename = "slope", format = "HFA")
```

Comment: so you'd like to have a vector with non-zero values?

Comment: please share the output of `str(eos)`

Comment: not able to post the whole str(eos) results, because its very long.

Comment: no problem. please check the answer below and give feedback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data is in `S4`, to change the values in `z` using the `@`

```
z@data@values <- z@data@values[z@data@values  > 0]
```

But since this was not said in the Question, I'll keep the normal filtering also

using `dplyr`

```
eos <- eos %>% na.omit() %>% filter(Value>0)
```

or `base`

```
eos <- eos[complete.cases(eos),]
eos <- eos[eos$Value>0,]
```

Comment: Got this error
> eos <- eos %>% na.omit() %>% filter(Value>0)
Error in UseMethod("filter_") : 
  no applicable method for 'filter_' applied to an object of class "c('RasterStack', 'Raster', 'RasterStackBrick', 'BasicRaster')"

Comment: that's why I asked for the structure of `eos` :)

Comment: it'd be easier, if you could share sample data for `eos`

Comment: I can't open the file, is the file ok?

Comment: Just checked its openning in ArcGIS but I am posting data again in the form of individual bands

Comment: link for the data.....https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwuacGknRgPNRF9kRXhTaEhZTFE/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Thanks @gi.rajan. I managed to open the first file and updated the answer above

Comment: @ mabdraboThanks for the help.. can u elaborate or give me link to understand about s4 data and what is z and why you are using @. I am a beginner in R programming..

Comment: glad I could help. here is a link explaining S4 http://adv-r.had.co.nz/S4.html (which will explain the @ as well)